# While loop trouble and reassigning a char variable in C (beginner)

Tags: c, while-loop, char, scanf

Hi this is my first post on this site, I've just started to learn C programming for school. I tried to look for other posts on my specific problem but got a little overwhelmed by the complexity of other answers. (so I apologize if it is redundant)

I am trying to write a code that takes 4 input numbers, prints them back to you backwards and then asks you if you want to do it again with a y/n option. I need some help with getting the computer to read the users y/n input and then continue/break the loop based on that. Here is what I have so far but I am getting some bad errors, thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int  x[5];
    char choice;

    choice = 'y'; //Assigned choice to y//

    while (choice == 'y')
    {

        printf("Please input up to four numbers seperated for example, 1 2 3 4 : ");

        scanf_s("%d %d %d %d", &x[0], &x[1], &x[2], &x[3]);

        printf("Your entries in reverse order are %d %d %d %d\n", x[3], x[2], x[1], x[0]); //This is working// 

        printf("Would you like to enter another set of numbers?  <y/n>:");

        scanf_s(" %c", choice); //Want this line to get an input y/n and if y, repeat the loop and if n, end the program//

    } 

    printf("Goodbye\n");

    system("Pause");

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: "bad errors" - tell us what they are.  Runtime errors or compiler errors?  Compiler messages are *diagnostic information* so when asking someone to diagnose a problem, it is helpful (polite even) if you provide that information.

Comment: Not related to the question, but you could initialise `choice` on declaration rather than declare then assign: `char choice = 'y' ;`

Comment: I suggest use `do while` loop against `while` loop. Then you will not have to set value of `choice` at the beginning.

Comment: Will post error code in the future, thanks for helping me simplify the char variable

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your call to `scanf_s` to get the input second time to the below:

```
scanf_s(" %c", &choice, 1);
```

Note that the 1 signifies the buffer size.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)

```
In the case of characters, a single character may be read as follows:

char c;
scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
scanf_s("%c", &choice, 1);
```

Scanf need pointer to variable. Otherwise scanf will not be able to put new value to "choice".
It is a popular mistake.

**EDIT:**
If you search for more information about scanf_s, you can base on scanf from standard library.
Scanf_s is functionally an exact counterpart of scanf.
The only difference is that the scanf_s is securer, because it has additional parameter to determine size of variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all learn to indent the code, that improves a lot of readability. Changing

```
scanf_s(" %c", choice);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

will remove all the errors from your code.

`